# Smart image search via Powershell

Tags: image, powershell, file-search

I am interested in file searching by custom properties. For example, I want to find all JPEG-images with certain dimensions. Something looks like

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Filter *.jpg -Recursive | where-object { $_.Dimension -eq '1024x768' }
```

I suspect it's about using of System.Drawing. How it can be done?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's actually pretty easy to do and your gut feeling about System.Drawing was in fact correct:

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.Drawing

$input | ForEach-Object { [Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_) }
```

Save that as `Get-Image.ps1` somewhere in your path and then you can use it.

Another option would be to add the following to your `$profile`:

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.Drawing

function Get-Image {
    $input | ForEach-Object { [Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_) }
}
```

which works pretty much the same. Of course, add fancy things like documentation or so as you see fit.

You can then *use* it like so:

```
gci -inc *.jpg -rec | Get-Image | ? { $_.Width -eq 1024 -and $_.Height -eq 768 }
```

Note that you should dispose the objects created this way after using them.

Of course, you can add a custom `Dimension` property so you could filter for that:

```
function Get-Image {
    $input |
        ForEach-Object { [Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_) } |
        ForEach-Object {
            $_ | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty Dimension ('{0}x{1}' -f $_.Width,$_.Height)
        }
}
```

Comment: You will you note in the answer, that the image should be disposed after the task finishes? Just to educate other scripters. Dispose method is often overlooked...

Comment: @stej: Eep, ok. Any way of doing so properly or automatically except for attaching `%{$_.Dispose()}` to the end of the pipeline?

Comment: I don't think there is better way than doing it manually as you propose.

Or wait until the end of Posh session. However, I typically open Posh console after I log in and close it before logging out, so that's not ideal.

Try/Finally could help as well, but that's overhead. I think a note is enough and let the rest on the readers ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative implementation as a (almost) one-liner:

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.Drawing

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Filter *.jpg -Recursive | ForEach-Object { [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_.FullName) } | Where-Object { $_.Width -eq 1024 -and $_.Height -eq 768 }
```

If you are going to need to run this command more than once, I would recommend [Johannes' more complete solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957828/smart-image-search-via-powershell/2957875#2957875) instead.