# List Fullname of image files of certain width or height, on Powershell

Tags: powershell, image, file-search

I'm trying to list the paths of all pictures with a width of 650, the intended result would be:

```
C:\test\650-width-picture1.png
C:\test\650-width-picture2.jpg
C:\test\subfolder\650-width-picture3.jpg
```

Among other things, I tried solutions from this old topic: [Smart image search via Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957828/smart-image-search-via-powershell)

1. Using the `Get-Image.ps1` described in the top solution, I tried the following command:

```
PS C:\test> Get-ChildItem -Filter *.png -Recurse | .\Get-Image | ? { $_.Width -eq 650 } | ft fullname
```

But for each file, it returns the following error:

```
Exception calling « FromFile » with « 1 » argument(s) : « 650-width-picture1.png »
At C:\test\Get-Image.ps1:3 : 27
+ $input | ForEach-Object { [Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_) }
+                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException
```

2. From the second solution of the same topic, the two-liner:

```
PS C:\test> Add-Type -Assembly System.Drawing
PS C:\test> Get-ChildItem -Filter *.png -Recurse | ForEach-Object { [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_.FullName) } | Where-Object { $_.Width -eq 650 }
```

returns only the image info, and I cannot get the path. Thus adding "| ft fullname" at the end returns nothing.

As someone new to Powershell, I struggle to get any further. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this, adding comments to help you understand the logic:

```
# load the drawing namespace
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

Get-ChildItem -Filter *.png -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    # for each `.png` file
    try {
        # instantiate the image for this file
        $img = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_.FullName)
        # if the image's `.Width` is equal to 650
        if ($img.Width -eq 650) {
            # output the `FileInfo` instance (from `Get-ChildItem` output)
            $_
        }
    }
    finally {
        # lastly, if the image could be instantiated
        if ($img) {
            # dispose it
            $img.Dispose()
        }
    }
    # select the `.FullName` property from the `FileInfo` instance
} | Select-Object FullName
```

Comment: Much easier to understand for me, thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: @puddingrocks any time :) glad it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think this is much easier with `exiftool` and it works in Powershell, CMD32, WSL, Linux/macOS `bash` and `zsh`:

```
exiftool -r -if "${ImageSize} and ${ImageWidth#} == 650" -p "$filepath" .
```